# Is it possible that not-null LiveData returns null?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is `LiveData` and View subscribes for the events

```kotlin
vm.fieldsValidated.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    enableContinueButton(it)   //<----- line 116
}
```

The problem is that in analytics I see a report about the crash:

```
Location: MyFile.kt line 116 in MyFragment$setupObservers$2.invoke
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: it must not be null
```

Function `enableContinueButton(state: Boolean)` is getting `not-null` values, as well as `LiveData` is not supposed to return `null`

```kotlin
protected val _fieldsValidated = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val fieldsValidated: LiveData<Boolean> =  _fieldsValidated
```

However, according to the crash report `LiveData` actually returns `null` in line 116 which causes the crash.

The question is - how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a suggestion for finding your issue. You can write an alternative version of MutableLiveData that enforces nullability. If you use this class, it should alert you with a compile error if you're setting its value using a nullable. Not completely foolproof, though, since there could be a maybe-nullable coming from Java code somewhere. If you can't find the issue at compile time with this or reproduce it, this should at least provide a runtime stack trace to where a null is being passed, since it will assert a non-null `value` parameter. So, you would at least get a more helpful stack trace from analytics.

```
class NonnullableMutableLiveData<T: Any>: MutableLiveData<T>() {
    override fun postValue(value: T) = super.postValue(value)
    override fun setValue(value: T) = super.setValue(value)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

LiveData is written in Java. It doesn't ensure null safety like Kotlin. You can read this [article](https://link.medium.com/eyD5qHgcFzb).

> LiveData is written in Java. It does allow setting it’s value to null.
> So the authors could add @Nullable annotation as we have them on other
> Jetpack libraries, right? No, as then you always need to handle
> nullable types in getValue or the Observer although you clearly might
> have declared your LiveData as non-null. The Generic is runtime
> information (for Java), annotations are compile-time information, they
> can’t solve this for us. And Java simply does not have null in the
> type system.

Comment: As mentioned in the article (in your response), it says that the crash could happen when you try to assigne `null` to the `non-null` Live Data. However, according to my crash report it says that `null` has been delivered to `.observer` (which is again `non-null`).

Comment: The observer is non-nullable, but the values passed to the observer could be null if you ever assigned null to `MutableLiveData.value`.